# Adding columns from other SQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have 4 tables. These tables are the result of counting the number of entries in another table based on a category. Here's the query used to create these tables:

```
SELECT Category, COUNT(*) AS Number 
FROM DATABASE.dbo.TABLE
GROUP BY Category;
```

Like I said, there are 4 of these tables created from different databases. So how could I write a query that ended up with the Category as Column1 but then the next four columns are the count results from the distinct 4 other databases?

**EDIT**

Incase any of that wasn't clear...

```
SELECT Category, COUNT(*) AS Number1
FROM DATABASE1.dbo.TABLE
GROUP BY Category;

SELECT Category, COUNT(*) AS Number2
FROM DATABASE2.dbo.TABLE
GROUP BY Category;

SELECT Category, COUNT(*) AS Number3
FROM DATABASE3.dbo.TABLE
GROUP BY Category;

SELECT Category, COUNT(*) AS Number4
FROM DATABASE4.dbo.TABLE
GROUP BY Category;
```

But what I want is this:

```
| Category | Number1 | Number2 | Number3 | Number4 |
|----------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
|          |         |         |         |         |
|          |         |         |         |         |
```

I tried

```
SELECT DATABASE1.dbo.TABLE.Category, DATABASE1.dbo.TABLE.COUNT(*), DATABASE2.dbo.TABLE.COUNT(*), DATABASE3.dbo.TABLE.COUNT(*), DATABASE4.dbo.TABLE.COUNT(*) 
FROM DATABASE1.dbo.TABLE
JOIN DATABASE2.dbo.TABLE
ON DATABASE1.dbo.TABLE=DATABASE2.dbo.TABLE
JOIN DATABASE3.dbo.TABLE
ON DATABASE2.dbo.TABLE=DATABASE3.dbo.TABLE
JOIN DATABASE4.dbo.TABLE
ON DATABASE3.dbo.TABLE=DATABASE4.dbo.TABLE
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: join to those tables on the category?

Comment: Have you linked these servers with your?

Comment: @scsimon, I looked at the join function but I'm not following what I should join on with these queries or if I can join on something with a `count(*)`

Comment: Check out my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `inner join`s to do this.

```
SELECT t1.category,t1.Number1,t2.Number2,t3.Number3,t4.Number4 
FROM (select Category,COUNT(*) AS Number1 from DATABASE1.dbo.TABLE GROUP BY Category) t1
join (select Category,COUNT(*) AS Number2 from DATABASE2.dbo.TABLE GROUP BY Category) t2
on t1.category=t2.category
join (select Category,COUNT(*) AS Number3 from DATABASE3.dbo.TABLE GROUP BY Category) t3
on t2.category=t3.category
join (select Category,COUNT(*) AS Number4 from DATABASE4.dbo.TABLE GROUP BY Category) t4
on t3.category=t4.category
```

Or a `full join` if a category isn't common across tables.

```
SELECT coalesce(t1.category,t2.category,t3.category,t4.category),
coalesce(t1.Number1,0),
coalesce(t2.Number2,0),
coalesce(t3.Number3,0),
coalesce(t4.Number4,0) 
FROM (select Category,COUNT(*) AS Number1 from DATABASE1.dbo.TABLE GROUP BY Category) t1
full join (select Category,COUNT(*) AS Number2 from DATABASE2.dbo.TABLE GROUP BY Category) t2
on t1.category=t2.category
full join (select Category,COUNT(*) AS Number3 from DATABASE3.dbo.TABLE GROUP BY Category) t3
on t2.category=t3.category
full join (select Category,COUNT(*) AS Number4 from DATABASE4.dbo.TABLE GROUP BY Category) t4
on t3.category=t4.category
```

Comment: What changed between the `cross join` and the `join`? I tried it with a `cross join` and it seemed to work.

Comment: yes..if you have multiple categories, cross join would produce many rows which isn;t necessary. `join` should work just fine if a category has to be present across all the tables. If not, you may have to use a `full join`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest `union all` and aggregation:

```
select category, sum(t1) as t1, sum(t2) as t2, sum(t3) as t3, sum(t4) as t4
from ((select category, 1 as t1, 0 as t2, 0 as t3, 0 as t4 
       from DATABASE1.dbo.TABLE
      ) union all
      (select category, 0 as t1, 1 as t2, 0 as t3, 0 as t4 
       from DATABASE2.dbo.TABLE
      ) union all
      (select category, 0 as t1, 0 as t2, 1 as t3, 0 as t4 
       from DATABASE3.dbo.TABLE
      ) union all
      (select category, 0 as t1, 0 as t2, 0 as t3, 1 as t4 
       from DATABASE4.dbo.TABLE t
      )
     ) tt
group by category;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple `Common Table Expression(CTE)` to get category and count and have join on those multiple `CTE`.

Your query should be :

```
with cte1 as
(
select category, count(*) as number1 from DATABASE1.dbo.TABLE group by category
),
cte2 as
(
select category, count(*) as number2 from DATABASE2.dbo.TABLE group by category
),
cte3 as
(
select category, count(*) as number3 from DATABASE3.dbo.TABLE group by category
),
cte4 as
(
select category, count(*) as number4 from DATABASE4.dbo.TABLE group by category
)
select c1.category, c1.number1,c2.number2,c3.number3,c4.number4
from cte1 c1 INNER JOIN cte2 c2 ON c1.category = c2.category  
INNER JOIN cte3 c3 ON c1.category = c3.category
INNER JOIN cte4 c4 ON c1.category = c4.category
```

I am not sure about the performance of this query but it's an option to have.